# Стороны компаса в градусах, кто может расказать? (OpenWeatherMap API)

Tags: python-3.x, openweathermap

От OpenWeatherMap API приходят градусы направления ветра, как сделать функцию для расчета направления как на компасе (Изображение) только в диапазоне градусов? [image: Компас с wiki]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл, сделал а кому интересно то вот ([>Тик<](https://ru.qaz.wiki/wiki/Points_of_the_compass)) или в гугле вбейте "`Как названы 32 точки компаса`" или "`32-роза ветров`" там будут градусы и названия (скорее всего) или вот если ссылка не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @RomanKonoval Ссылка на wiki не может устареть

Comment: @RomanKonoval Надеюсь это картинка решит все проблемы потому что скопировать это незя.

Comment: Эта картинка не отвечает на ваш же вопрос. И (наверное я просто старомодный) никакой новой информации эта таблица не несет. Кто не спал в школе на уроке географии или хотя бы читал книжки про пиратов и так знает, какая буква какое направление означает.